# Lexer.nextToken() - var tokenStartMarker = this._input.mark(); is not a function error

Tags: javascript, antlr4

Just built a grammar on latest antlr, compiled to java and tested, works fine.

Compiled to javascript and attempted to test it, but I get an error on line 111 of Lexer.js indicating that `var tokenStartMarker = this._input.mark();` <== .mark() is not a function.

Here's my javascript code to load and parse the grammar:

```
var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
var BQLXLexer = require('grammar/BQLXLexer').BQLXLexer;
var BQLXParser = require('grammar/BQLXParser').BQLXParser;

function validatePipeline(script) {
    var chars = antlr4.InputStream(script);
    var lexer = new BQLXLexer(chars);
    var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    var parser = new BQLXParser(tokens);
    parser.buildParseTrees = true;
    var ast = parser.pipeline();
    console.log(ast);
}
```

the line `var ast = parser.pipeline();` is what eventually calls into the Lexer and produces the error in the runtime.

I have tested on both 4.7.2 and 4.7.1 version of the javascript runtime, and both produce the same error on the same line, 111 of Lexer.js.

Not sure what else to try here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after the 5th time reviewing my code, I realised that I forgot a `new` statement on this line:  `var chars = antlr4.InputStream(script);`.

The line should be revised to read `var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(script);`, which then resolves the error.